# How to convert serialize array value to JSON in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, serialization, serializearray

i have serialize array like this

`rate_3=26&rate_8=67&rate_12=98` etc..,

now i need to change this array as json type

```
    {
        "ID": "3",
        "Rate": "26"
    },
    {
        "ID": "8",
        "Rate": "67"
    },
    {
        "ID": "3",
        "Rate": "26"
   } .., 
   etc
```

so i tried like this but its not working... please some one help me.

```
        var o = {};
        var a = table.$('input, select').serialize();
        $.each(a, function() 
        {
        if (o[this.name] !== undefined) 
            {
            if (!o[this.name].push) 
                {
                    o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
                }
                o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
            }
        else 
            {
                o[this.name] = this.value || '';
            }
        });
        return o;
```

i m using datatable so i just need to get Datatables serialize array only for that used this line

`var a = table.$('input, select').serialize();`

even i tried with json2.js also but when i use json2.js it forcing the page to submit

```
var data_2 = JSON.stringify(block_form.serializeArray());
```

Comment: `this but its not working` - What is actually happening and what is actually expected?

Comment: The `.serialize` function returns a string, not an array. So you can't then `.each` it and expect it to work. Not sure why you are using `.serialize` in the first place when it seems it would be easier to just build the object you need from the selected options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data format is reliably in the `rate_N=X&` format, you can use simple string splitting to parse out the values. This appears to be similar to how query strings are formatted and, if that's the case, you shouldn't run into (m)any unusual entities.

First, you'll want to break each key-value pair apart (on the `&`). Then split each pair on the `=` to produce the key and value. You'll need to parse the ID out of the key (cut the `rate_` off the front), which substr will work well for.

```js
var data = "rate_3=26&rate_8=67&rate_12=98";

var pairs = data.split('&').reduce(function(collect, pair) {
  var kv = pair.split('=');
  var name = kv[0].substr(kv[0].indexOf('_') + 1);
  collect.push({
    id: name,
    rate: kv[1]
  });
  return collect;
}, []);

document.getElementById('results').textContent = JSON.stringify(pairs);
```

```html
<pre id="results"></pre>
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple method is to [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the results of a regex match, pushing new objects into the resulting array:

```
var out = str.match(/\d+=\d+/g).map(function (el) {
    var arr = el.split('=');
    return { id: arr[0], rate: arr[1] };
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ujd800yp/2/)

Convert the output array to JSON with `JSON.stringify(out)`.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/43hnftaf/

```
var str = 'rate_3=26&rate_8=67&rate_12=98'
var arr = str.split('&').map(function(element) { 
    return element.replace(/^rate_/, '');
}).map(function(element) {
    var elements = element.split('=');
    return {
        "ID" : elements[0],
        "Rate" : elements[1]
    };
});
console.log(arr);
```